# Alter "Quick Action" Behavior in C#

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I don't know what I did, but the default behavior for the quick action brought up by Ctrl + '.' is now to qualify a referenced type with a namespace as opposed to adding a new using statement at the top of my source file.  While this works, it is very annoying (especially when referencing the same namespace repeatedly in the same source file).

Example:
If I type ISomeType I now get a code suggestion like:

"Replace ISomeType with My.NameSpace.ISomeType"

Where what I would prefer is:

"{}+ Using My.Namespace"

I have been searching through various settings and options without any luck (note: This is occurring while editing C# / .cs files and not related to MVC/Razor [for which I have seen open bugs]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shutting down the IDE and restarting ended up fixing my issue.  Very weird.